# What does the test “if (i && (i- 1))” mean?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement, logical-and

I don't understand this line of code:

> ```
> if (i && (i - 1))
>     printf("%d\n", p[i - 1]);
> ```

```
int main(void) {
    int p[7] = {-5, 1, 4, -7, 2, 8, 0};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
         if (i && (i - 1))
            printf("%d\n", p[i - 1]);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It means `if (i != 0 && (i - 1) != 0)`. Or simply `if (i != 0 && i != 1)`.

Comment: Where did you find this code? It's extremely weird.

Comment: Well, I haven't found it I just got that code from proffesor and he said to me to try to understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition of this if statement

```
if (i && (i - 1))
```

can be rewritten for clarity like

```
if (i != 0 && (i - 1) != 0)
```

In the condition there is checked whether the current value of the index i is equal to 0. And if it is not equal to 0 then whether the preceding value of the index i - 1 is equal to 0.

This evaluates to true when i is not equal to 0 and is not equal to 1.

So the condition evaluates to true starting from the index i equal to 2.

So the loop outputs all elements of the array except the first element and the last element.

Answer (score 2):

If `i != 0` AND `i - 1 != 0` THEN printing the `i - 1` element of `p`. This `i != 0` check need since otherwise at first iteration it would be `0 - 1 = -1` as index which is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

In general, in C, values that are not 0 will be evaluated as `true` while zero will be evaluated as `false`.

This line:

```
if (i && (i - 1))
   printf("%d\n", p[i - 1]);
```

basically checks whether or not the value of `i` and `i-1` is different from `0`.  The meaning of that is that the 2 first elements in the array won't be printed since for `i=0` we'll get `i` which is `false` and for `i=1` we will get `(i-1)` which is `false`

So the outcome of this code should be printing of `4, -7, 2, 8, 0`

Answer (score 1):

`if (i && (i - 1))` is basically `if (i != 0 && i != 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Condition statement `(i && (i - 1)` is nothing but `i!=0 && i != 1`

In short the 0 and 1 are skipped in the iteration and elements from 1 to 5 are printed

Loop boils down to this,

```
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", p[i]);
}
```

Comment: @UncleBilly: as print is from `p[i-1]`,